# How to create the download link?

Tags: magento-2.1, pdf, download-link

I am using `Magento 2.1` and I want to display download link in my **Contact us** page.

[image]

If I click in this link then I want to display **PDF** file.

Comment: You can follow the steps mentions in the @Renaud answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/149584/magento-2-how-to-add-or-insert-pdf-file-in-a-cms-page

Comment: Please accept and upvote answer if it's useful for you. So, other developer can use this answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### For download PDF :

```
<a href="{{media url="pdf/1.pdf"}}" download>Please download PDF</a>
```

### For view PDF :

```
<a href="{{media url="pdf/1.pdf"}}" target="_blank">Please download PDF</a>
```

### Example output :

```
<a href="http://domanin.com/pub/media/pdf/1.pdf">Please download PDF</a>
```

### File path location should be :

```
{MagentoRootFolder}/pub/media/pdf/1.pdf
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a Download link on the `CMS page` or `CMS Static block`, You can use the below code:

The file location to store the pdf is

> app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{themeName}/web/pdf/001.pdf

How to view and download file in CMS Block:

```
<a href="{{view url="pdf/001.pdf"}}" download="001.pdf">Please download PDF</a>
```

How to open in a new tab:

```
<a href="{{view url="pdf/001.pdf"}}" target="_blank">Next Page PDF</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

1- Adding link in contact form 2- Adding pdf in server.

1. > app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{themeName}/Magento_Contact/templates/form.phtml

   ```
   <a href="<?php echo $block->getViewFileUrl('pdf/001.pdf'); ?>" download="001.pdf"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Please download Appli...'))?></a>
   ```
2. > app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{themeName}/web/pdf/001.pdf

   Now when you click on this link, you'll download the pdf `001.pdf` file.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the response,  If I create Content-->blocks or Content-->pages then how can I give this dowmload link ?

Comment: <a href="{{media url="pdf/001.pdf"}}" download="001.pdf">Please download...</a>

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add Download link on `CMS page` or `CMS Static block`, You can use below code.

```
<a href="{{media url="pdf/001.pdf"}}" download="001.pdf">Please download PDF</a>
```

If you want to Show pdf in new tab, You can use below code

```
<a href="{{media url="pdf/001.pdf"}}" target="_blank">Please download PDF</a>
```

And location of pdf file will be

> {MagentoRoot}/pub/media/pdf/001.pdf

Hope above will help!

Answer (score 0):

Place your pdf inside the web folder of your module then run all Magento commands. You can see your pdf to be generated in pub/static folder using that you can give downloadable link

```
<a id="sample-file-link" href="<?php echo $block->getViewFileUrl('Vendor_module/file.pdf'); ?> ">Download  link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done same functionality working fine. Now I want to save customer data in custom table on download pdf. Please anyone help.